# Angular 4 - Http error doesn't get to custom global error handler

Tags: angular, error-handling, global

i have a global event handler

```
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
errorMsg: string;
stackTrace: string;
constructor(private injector: Injector) {
}
handleError(error) {
    var router = this.injector.get(Router);
    this.errorMsg = JSON.parse(error._body).message;
    this.stackTrace = JSON.parse(error._body).stackTrace;
    router.navigate(["error", { errMsg: this.errorMsg, stackTrace:this.stackTrace }]);
    //alert(error._body);
}
}
```

I included it into providers:

```
 providers: [PricingEventService, {
    provide: ErrorHandler,
    useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
}],
```

I'm hoping GlobalErrorHandler will be called if there is an exception while doing HTTP request (post or get) - i threw an exception inside the post method

```
 saveEvent(event: PricingEvent): Observable<string> {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post('/pricingevent', event, options)
        .map((response: Response) => <string>response.json().value.errMsg);
}
```

However, the GlobalErrorHandler was never called - if i use a .catch method in the service call, it will capture the exception the i threw from the server.

Can anyone tell me why is that and how to fix that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(data), {headers: headers})
       .map(resp => resp.json())
       .catch(err => throw new Error('I am not working'));
```

Comment: the last thing i want to do is add .catch all over the place.. Although i'm pretty sure this would work.